# Label hist() axis in a multiplot from loops

Tags: r, loops

I'd like to plot the headers of my dataframe in the histogram axis. My code is:

```
#histogram
     par(mfrow=c(2,5)) #multiplot parameters
        loop.vector <- 1:10
        for (i in loop.vector){
            z <- dados.no.id[,i] #dataframe without id column
            n <- dados[1,i] #dataframe with id column
            hist(z, main = (" ")) #histogram plot function
            xlab = paste(names(n))} #trying to plot headers from dataframe
```

Below is a stretch of my data (`dados`):

```r
structure(list(id = 1:2, A = c(1.27, 1.27), B = c(0.33, -0.31
), C = c(4.47, 2.6), D = c(0.09, 0.09), E = c(-0.18, -0.01), 
    F = c(0.17, 0.22), G = c(178.46, 95.57), H = c(10.98, 7.33
    ), I = c(15042, 15038.09), J = c(6.89, 6.89)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
#   id    A     B    C    D     E    F      G     H        I    J
# 1  1 1.27  0.33 4.47 0.09 -0.18 0.17 178.46 10.98 15042.00 6.89
# 2  2 1.27 -0.31 2.60 0.09 -0.01 0.22  95.57  7.33 15038.09 6.89
```

Comment: Please either provide sample data for *your* data or use a public dataset (such as `iris`, `mtcars`, or `ggplot2::diamonds`, many others exist).

Comment: Hi @r2evans, i've just inserted one sample of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS: when you ask questions, please try to make them reproducible for us. In this case, `dados.no.id` is still missing. I'm inferring that it is really just `dados` with the first column removed, which I will proxy by using `i+1` instead of `i` in the indexing.

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,5))                 # multiplot parameters
loop.vector <- 1:10
for (i in loop.vector){
  z <- dados[,i+1]                # dataframe without id column
  hist(z, main = (" "),           # histogram plot function
       xlab = names(dados)[i+1])  # trying to plot headers from dataframe
}
```

Incidentally, it's possible (likely, even) that you have the `Hmisc` package installed, in which case you can come close with just:

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,5))
Hmisc::hist.data.frame(dados[,-1], n.unique=1)
# or optionally
library(Hmisc)
par(mfrow=c(2,5))
hist(dados[,-1], n.unique=1)
```

(The use of `n.unique=1` is required only because of the sample data you provided. If you look at the source of the function, you'll see that it only shows a histogram for a column if there are at least `n.unique` values, and some of your columns have only one unique value in its two rows.)

The use of `dados[,-1]` will plot all except the first column (`id` in your data). (I think this is approximating the `dados.no.id` you suggested in your code.)

Comment: it was a helpful set of tips.